# Can I replace an attribute with a lambda WITHOUT changing access syntax?

Tags: python, testing, lambda

I have a boolean that is used all over a system I've just joined (it's Django's settings.DEBUG, but that's not really important, since this would be handy for testing, as well.)

I want to prevent non-django use of this attribute. Developers using my system should get an exception, telling them to use a different attribute:

```
settings.DEBUG = lambda: return_bool_or_throw_exception_if_caller_forbidden()
```

The trouble is, switching to a lambda requires that accessors change:

```
#instead of:
if settings.DEBUG:
#now:
if settings.DEBUG():
```

But this would require changing all the reads of DEBUG in Django code, which is unacceptable in my situation. Can I deliver a lambda or a function with no arguments in such a way that consumers can access the thing without function call semantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could monkey patch the settings class and set DEBUG to a descriptor:

```
def DEBUG(self):
    return return_bool_or_throw_exception_if_caller_forbidden()

settings.__class__.DEBUG = property(DEBUG)
```